# How to using Firebase Notification. I can't turn on display device with received notification?

Tags: xamarin.android

I followed the instructions to send notice of Firebase Notification following the instructions of Microsoft. But when the android device receives the notification does not light up the screen. I tried attaching WakeLock to turn on display but it didn't work?
All method are in the OnMessageReceived function.

```
var wakeLock = powerManager.NewWakeLock(WakeLockFlags.ScreenDim | 
                            WakeLockFlags.AcquireCausesWakeup, "Demo");
            wakeLock.Acquire(2 * 1000);
//////Send Notification here

wakeLock.Release();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use this method that uses power manager to turn on the screen light

```
private List<WakeLock> TurnDeviceLightOn(Context context)
    {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.PowerService);
        bool isScreenOn = pm.IsInteractive;
        if (!isScreenOn)
        {
            WakeLock wl = pm.NewWakeLock(WakeLockFlags.Full | WakeLockFlags.AcquireCausesWakeup | WakeLockFlags.OnAfterRelease, "myLock");
            wl.Acquire(10000);
            WakeLock wl_cpu = pm.NewWakeLock(WakeLockFlags.Partial, "myCpuLock");
            wl_cpu.Acquire(10000);
            return new List<WakeLock>() { wl, wl_cpu };
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This method returns the wake-locks which can be released at a later point of time

Comment: I using FirebaseMessagingService. How to the context in method?
"MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService"

Comment: Umm yeah, I know you can use it there?

Comment: Thanks you. I used your method. When debugging turn on display, but running real application does not turn on display

Comment: Umm you mean in debug mode its working but not working while in released build?

Comment: Yes. I also do not understand why the release build application does not turn on display in device android

Comment: The reason is that when your app is in background this method is never called you might wanna change your notification payload!

Comment: hey! I want to clicked notification in notification center on device to open page "xaml". I using OnNewIntent but when there are lots of notifications, Onnewintent opens many pages "xaml". I want open is one page?

Comment: Check if it is already in the navigation stack and do not push if it is! https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/127493/how-to-check-a-page-is-in-the-navigation-stack-or-not

Comment: Thanks you so much. I deloy in android SDK 9.0, with device received notification. I try show pull down in center notification but don't show. Can you help me?

Comment: Can you add more details into a new question with some code so I know what you are dealing with? Link it here once done!

Comment: I want app run or close with received notification in device android. I upload image in page https://imgur.com/a/TEErAl4 and I using properties "SetPriority" in chanel but don't showing

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, your code can turn on screen when device is sleep, but for Firebase notification, you should know:

Notification messages are delivered to your onMessageReceived callback only when your app is in the foreground.

If your app is in the background or closed then a notification message is shown in the notification center, and any data from that message is passed to the intent that is launched as a result of the user tapping on the notification. So the onMessageReceived event is not fired. If you add your code in this event, I think it doesn't work.

Comment: I want when the device receives a notification, the screen of the device is sleeping, it will light up.